# How to play the SMS alert sound in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, sms, alert

I'd like my app to play an alert sound and vibrate the phone when a certain page is loaded.  Specifically, I want to play the SMS alert sound effect that the user has picked from the settings.  I already have the vibration done, but I'm not sure how to get the SMS alert sound to play.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't have access to the phone's alerts and sounds.

One way to do this, is import a media in your project, with it's build action set to content and use the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to play a sound, by calling its `.Play()` method in code-behind.